# How can I drop the duplicate not unique data using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `users`, which have `first name` and `last name`, I would like to remain one record with the same `first name` and `last name`, other records will be dropped.

For example:

```
first name: Peter last name: White
first name: Mary last name: White
first name: John last name: Brown
first name: Peter last name: White
```

After execute the SQL:

```
first name: Peter last name: White
first name: Mary last name: White
first name: John last name: Brown
```

Comment: Step 1 - decide what record you want to keep and why.

Comment: The first appear keep, and rest of them delete. Because the programme have a bug, it writes more data in the database. So, need to be remove from the database.

Comment: How do you define the first?  Are these records timestamped?  Is there an autoincrement primary key?

Comment: Sorry, no primary key and time stamp.

Answer (score 2):

A nice feature of SQL Server is the ability to use CTEs for updates, inserts, and deletes.  Here is one method:

```
with fordeletion as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by fname, lname order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from t
     )
delete from fordeletion
    where seqnum > 1;
```